# Laravel query with multiple wheres depending on conditions

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to build a query.

I want to add multiple `where` by condititions, but I can't achieve it.

If I do it, it works:

```
$query = Frete::all();

//or

$query = Frete::where('estado_destino_id', '=', $request->destino);
```

But, what I want is to set multiple `where` based on some conditions, something like this:

```
public function fretes(Request $request){

    $query = Frete::all();
    if ($request->destino){
        $query->where('estado_destino_id', '=', $request->destino);
    }

    if ($request->veiculo){
        $query->where('veiculo_id', '=', $request->veiculo);
    }

    $query->get();
    return response()->json($query);
}
```

The above code returns all table and it is ignoring wheres.

I also tried this `$query = DB::table('fretes');` instead of `$query = Frete::all();`

This way, JSON returned is:

```
    {
    "connection": {},
    "grammar": {},
    "processor": {},
    "bindings": {
        "select": [],
        "from": [],
        "join": [],
        "where": [
            1
        ],
        "having": [],
        "order": [],
        "union": []
    },
    "aggregate": null,
    "columns": null,
    "distinct": false,
    "from": "fretes",
    "joins": null,
    "wheres": [
        {
            "type": "Basic",
            "column": "estado_destino_id",
            "operator": "=",
            "value": 1,
            "boolean": "and"
        }
    ],
    "groups": null,
    "havings": null,
    "orders": null,
    "limit": null,
    "offset": null,
    "unions": null,
    "unionLimit": null,
    "unionOffset": null,
    "unionOrders": null,
    "lock": null,
    "operators": [
        "=",
        "<",
        ">",
        "<=",
        ">=",
        "<>",
        "!=",
        "<=>",
        "like",
        "like binary",
        "not like",
        "ilike",
        "&",
        "|",
        "^",
        "<<",
        ">>",
        "rlike",
        "regexp",
        "not regexp",
        "~",
        "~*",
        "!~",
        "!~*",
        "similar to",
        "not similar to",
        "not ilike",
        "~~*",
        "!~~*"
    ],
    "useWritePdo": false
}
```

I've seen many posts and I've tried to implement it without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `all()` method doesn't return a query. It executes `SELECT * FROM table` and returns the results. You need to start a new query then add the conditions to it  `Frete::query();`

```
public function fretes(Request $request){

    $query = Frete::query();
    if ($request->destino){
        $query->where('estado_destino_id', '=', $request->destino);
    }

    if ($request->veiculo){
        $query->where('veiculo_id', '=', $request->veiculo);
    }

    $results = $query->get();
    return response()->json($results);
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it always return blank to me `{}`.

Comment: @NimbusSoftworks Whoops, I forgot to make sure you capture the results. I've fixed my answer with code that should work.

Comment: It works. I was near to it, but It not clear in the docs for beginners. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use here [conditional-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
public function fretes(Request $request){

        $query = Frete::when($request->destino,function($q,$request) {
          return   $query->where('estado_destino_id', '=', $request->destino);
        })->when($request->veiculo,function($q,$request) {
          return   $query->where('veiculo_id', '=', $request->veiculo);
        })->get();

    return response()->json($query);
}
```

> Sometimes you may want clauses to apply to a query only when something
>   else is true. For instance you may only want to apply a where
>   statement if a given input value is present on the incoming request.
>   You may accomplish this using the  when method.

Comment: It will be helpful for me, but @jfadich anwer is what I was looking for.